# Discord Timesheets Bot remove error: Interaction has already been acknowledged

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm currently making a discord timesheets bot. I have a problem, where it always said Interaction has already been acknowledged. I already tried making it new but that also didn't help. Here is the code:

```
Fehler bei der Interaktion: DiscordAPIError: Interaction has already been acknowledged.
    at RequestHandler.execute (/home/container/projects/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:350:13)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (/home/container/projects/node_modules/discord.js/src/rest/RequestHandler.js:51:14)
    at async SelectMenuInteraction.deferReply (/home/container/projects/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/interfaces/InteractionResponses.js:61:5)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (/home/container/projects/Sprachen/germanCommands.js:541:5) {
  method: 'post',
  path: '/interactions/1180054724268015626/aW50ZXJhY3Rpb246MTE4MDA1NDcyNDI2ODAxNTYyNjphcTQzWmFMczVOQjlkYlNPY1poSGM5czM1aHNwSXJ3SkxSTlpmZWNoUTNVVkYzQzdIZHNNZm1kQWhKMTAzSlBKSURxYVZqUE9MNjZhMUVkNzNKeVRyc0NCTU9ta3VHeXo5S1JkbE9PRENXSnRYb0dzRzl5UWMxbXc3TjJmVW9rbg/callback',
  code: 40060,
  httpStatus: 400,
  requestData: { json: { type: 5, data: [Object] }, files: [] }
}
```

```
client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
  try {
    if (!interaction.isSelectMenu() || interaction.customId !== 'Userremove') return;

    // Bestätigen Sie die Interaktion, um zu signalisieren, dass eine Antwort folgen wird
    await interaction.deferReply();

    const userIdToRemove = interaction.values[0];
    const guildId = interaction.guild.id;

    // Suche nach dem Benutzer in UserStats
    let userStats = await UserStats.findOne({ guildId: guildId, userId: userIdToRemove });
    if (!userStats || !userStats.signInTimestamp) {
      await interaction.editReply("Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten beim Austragen des Benutzers.");
      return;
    }

    // Aktualisiere die UserStats
    userStats.signInTimestamp = null;
    await userStats.save();

    // Benachrichtigung, dass der Benutzer ausgetragen wurde
    await interaction.editReply({ content: `${interaction.guild.members.cache.get(userIdToRemove)?.displayName || 'Unbekannter Benutzer'} wurde ausgetragen!` });

    // Aktualisiere das Dashboard und logge die Aktion
    await updateDashboard(guildId);
    await logAction(guildId, `${interaction.guild.members.cache.get(userIdToRemove)?.displayName || 'Unbekannter Benutzer'} wurde von ${interaction.member.displayName || interaction.user.tag} ausgetragen!\nEingetragene Zeit: ${formattedTime}`);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Fehler bei der Interaktion:", error);
    if (!interaction.replied) {
      await interaction.reply("Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten.");
    } else {
      await interaction.followUp("Ein Fehler ist aufgetreten.");
    }
  }
});
```

I hope that you guys can help me. Thanks